# Failed to compile with 1 error in ./src/main.js

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I got this below error suddenly with no package.json updated. I have attached the main.js and package.json. And I believe the error is caused by vuetify since it successfully build if I comment out the vuetify. Thank you for your time and help in advance! It was no error until two weeks ago. I noticed that it happened after package-lock.json get updated. I have try building the app in docker to isolate it is not my environmental problem.

````
error  in ./src/main.js

Module not found: Error: Default condition should be last one

ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
Error: Build failed with errors.
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:207:23
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:148:8
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
at Hook.eval \[as callAsync\] (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE \[as \_callAsync\] (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at Cache.shutdown (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1228:15
at Hook.eval \[as callAsync\] (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE \[as \_callAsync\] (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at Compiler.close (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1221:23)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:147:16
at finalCallback (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:441:32)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:458:13
at Hook.eval \[as callAsync\] (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:24:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE \[as \_callAsync\] (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at onCompiled (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:456:21)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1199:17
at Hook.eval \[as callAsync\] (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE \[as \_callAsync\] (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1195:33
at finalCallback (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:2795:11)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3100:11
at Hook.eval \[as callAsync\] (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:6:1)
at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE \[as \_callAsync\] (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
at /Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:3093:38
at eval (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:15:1)
at eval (eval at create (/Users/takocheung/PersonalSite/frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), \<anonymous\>:14:1)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)```


main.js
`
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import App from "@/App.vue";
import router from "@/router/index";
import { GChart } from "vue-google-charts";
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const store = createStore({
    state: {
        isNavOpen: false,
        isChatOpen: false,
        hwTimeLineShown: false,
        hwDetailsShown: false,
        fsTimeLineShown: false,
        fsDetailsShown: false,
        cstTimeLineShown: false,
        cstDetailsShown: false,
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleNav(state) {
            state.isNavOpen = !state.isNavOpen;
        },
        toggleChat(state) {
            state.isChatOpen = !state.isChatOpen;
        },
        offChat(state) {
            state.isChatOpen = false;
        },
        toggleHwDetails(state) {
            state.hwDetailsShown = !state.hwDetailsShown;
        },
        toggleHwTimeLine(state) {
            state.hwTimeLineShown = !state.hwTimeLineShown;
        },
        toggleFsDetails(state) {
            state.fsDetailsShown = !state.fsDetailsShown;
        },
        toggleFsTimeLine(state) {
            state.fsTimeLineShown = !state.fsTimeLineShown;
        },
        toggleCstDetails(state) {
            state.cstDetailsShown = !state.cstDetailsShown;
        },
        toggleCstTimeLine(state) {
            state.cstTimeLineShown = !state.cstTimeLineShown;
        },
    },
});

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(GChart);
app.use(router);
app.use(vuetify);
app.use(store);

// app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tagName) => {
//  return tagName === "vue-advanced-chat" || tagName === "emoji-picker";
// };

app.mount("#app");
`

package.json
`
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --watch",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "reset": "rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm i"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.30.1",
    "firebase": "^9.20.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "lamejs": "^1.2.1",
    "storage": "^0.2.0",
    "v-header": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-advanced-chat": "^2.0.7",
    "vue-google-charts": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vue-scroll-progress": "^1.1.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.1.15",
    "vuex" : "^4.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.21.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.8",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.11.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
`
````